# Keep value persistance in MVC after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to show a user name at the top menu, I add it to ViewData, but in search page at search page as I am doing post back, the data is not there any more. How I can make in persistence, without using tempdata. viewbag or session please.

This is my login page that show search view after successful login.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LogInRequest logInRequest)
    {
           User user = null;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            user = await GetUserByEmailAndPassword(logInRequest.UserName, logInRequest.Password);
            if (user.Id != 0)
            {
                  ViewData["Name"] = user.Name;
                  return View("~/Views/LoanDriver/Search.cshtml");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("~/Views/LoanDriver/Dashboard.cshtml");
                }
              ......
            return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
          }
```

and this is my search view:

```
@model CarFinance.Garage.Web.Models.SearchResult

@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SecondaryPage.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "LoanDriver", FormMethod.Post))
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   .......}
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/LoanDriver/SearchResult.cshtml")
```

and this is the master page that shows the menu at the top:

```
@{
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterLayout.cshtml";
  }
@section header {

               @(ViewData["Name"])
```

It shows for first time but when I put search button that refresh (postback) to the page Name is empty.

Comment: Use view models with a base view model containing the property (and set its value in each request) and then reference the base model in the layout

Comment: @Stephen Muecke can you please expian moew or link to how I can use?

Comment: Using `@(ViewData["Name"])` will also work for you (or `ViewBag.Name`) but you need to set the value in each request - so in every method you need to get the current user and set it (just as you have done in the Login POST method)

Answer (score 0):

Best way I would do this is create yourself a `BaseController`

so basically

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // Here you can run any code you like, this code will always run after any action has been executed
        ViewData["Name"] = "User Name";
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then on your controllers you just inherit BaseController

`public class HomeController : BaseController`

So now on every page request it will first populate the the `ViewData["Name"]`